# OpenLayers DrawFeature override double click

Tags: openlayers-2, editing

Can anyone explain how I can ovveride the dblclick event when I'm using an OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature? I see there is parameter in the constructor for handlerOptions - Used to set non-default properties on the control’s handler. My handler is just an OpenLayers.Handler.Path.

I want to run some custom validation when a user double clicks so that they can continue the sketch should they fail.

Double click --> "you've drawn something stupid are you sure you want to finish?" --> No ---> carry on sketching

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1):

if you make some edit here `OpenLayers / lib / OpenLayers / Handler / Path.js` , you can reach what you want.

code:

```
/**
* APIMethod: finishGeometry
* Finish the geometry and send it back to the control.
*/
    finishGeometry: function() {
        var index = this.line.geometry.components.length - 1;
        this.line.geometry.removeComponent(this.line.geometry.components[index]);
        this.removePoint();
        this.finalize();
    },

    /**
* Method: dblclick
* Handle double-clicks.
*
* Parameters:
* evt - {Event} The browser event
*
* Returns:
* {Boolean} Allow event propagation
*/
    dblclick: function(evt) {
        if(!this.freehandMode(evt)) {
            this.finishGeometry();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

i hope it helps you...